# how do i install mod_wsgi in ubuntu

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-9.10

I want to start developing website with `Django` but I'm unable to install `mod_wsgi` in my `ubuntu 9.10` in which `*python2.6*` is there by default.

Comment: It's more of a serverfault.com question...

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Comment: I was trying to install on a server and for some reason:
apt-cache search "wsgi"

Didn't find anything.